# Good practice for re-usable form component in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to write a re-usable form component for a "user". I'd like to be able to use it in both an "edit" and a "create" flow. I'd pass it a user object, it would validate as a user enters/modifies the user data and it would update the user object. The parent component (e.g EditUser, CreateUser) will do the actual saving.

How should I do this without mutating props? I've avoided using events so far because I'd need to fire one on every user input, passing a copy of the user object back up to the parent (I think).

EDIT: adding some (non-working) code to demonstrate. I can't share my exact code.

**Parent component**

```
<template>
    <div >
        <h1>header</h1>
        <MyFormComponent
            v-model="user"
        >
        </MyFormComponent>

        <button>Save</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {

    data(){

        return {
            user: {
                name: 'User 1'
            }
        }

    }

}

</script>
```

**Form component**

```
<template>

    <form>
        <MyFormInputComponent
            v-model="user.name"
        ></MyFormInputComponent>
    </form>

</template>

<script>

export default {

    props: ['user'],

    model: {
        prop: 'user'
    }   

}

</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly your context, but this is how I use to do:

First, you don't need both components `Parent` and `Child`. You can do all you want inside Form Component.

To deal with the differences between create and edit modes, an option is computed property based on current route (if they are different according to create/edit operations).

Using this property, you decide if data will be fetched from API, if delete button will has shown, the title of the page and so on.

Here is an example:

```
async created() {
  if (this.isEditMode) {
    // fetch form data from API according to User ID and copy to a local form
  },
},
computed: {
  formTitle() {
    return (this.isEditMode ? 'Update' : 'Create') + ' User';
  },
}
```